# create route for my backend website in zf3

Tags: php, zend-framework3

i have in module/config/module.config.php :

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'home-backend' => [
            'type' => Literal::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/backend',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'backend' => [
            'type' => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/backend[/:controller[/:action]]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => [
                'wildcard' => [
                    'type' => 'Wildcard'
                ]
            ]
        ],  
    ],
],
```

when i call : http://mysite/backend/index/index
error :
Page not found.
The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Controller:
index (resolves to invalid controller class or alias: index)

what is problem??

Answer (score 0):

Seem you missed configuration for `controller`. Please add configuration for controller to `module/config/module.config.php`.

If you use `factory`, the configuration will be like this.

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\IndexController::class => Controller\IndexControllerFactory::class,
    ]
],
```

If you don't use `factory`, the configuration will be like this

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ]
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Point that you should not use same route patten twice. Here I see `/backend` is used twice. Otherwise the route pattern for `backend` route is not well-formatted.

Hope you would understand [the better way here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30654894/7935051)!